# alternatives to document.location.reload(true) using html #s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is connected to a DB and I am using

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

at the end of a few functions to reload the page. Is there any way to make it reload to a specified part of the page? kinda like when you write it directly to the address bar it would end in `/mypage.html#part6`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

`window.location.href = window.location.href + '?' + <randomizer>`

The `<randomizer>` bit above is to simulate the `true` argument to `reload()`

Comment: and then the `'?'` would be the `'#part6'` ?

Comment: No, that would be a little tricky. It won't auto-reload if theres only a hash.